# What is a "flight wheel"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

At [Planetary.org](https://www.planetary.org/articles/08190630-curiosity-wheel-damage) I read this:

> Below is a photo of a **flight wheel** -- that is, one of the six that's sitting on Mars today.

Never heard flight wheel before and couldn't find anything when I searched for the expression. To me it looks like a regular wheel (how regular a wheel that is used on a vehicle on Mars can be).

Edit: and, BTW, I associated to "fly wheel", which seems far fetched and probably isn't correct.

Comment: Does the image caption not answer this? "A Curiosity wheel before it was attached to the rover and **flown to Mars,** labeled with all of its component parts." (my emphasis here)

Comment: You find 'flight' wheels and spokes on some bicycles, scooters, etc; the spokes are flexible and often curved. Often made of carbon fiber/fibre, originally a 1990s brand "Fiber Flight". The Curiosity wheels have curved titanium spokes.

Answer (score 5):

A 1996 NASA document ([*Wheel Abrasion Experiment Metals Selection
for Mars Pathfinder Mission*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/42775197.pdf)) explains the jargon, albeit obliquely:

> The final flight hardware was built using three strips of 707 l-T6 aluminum ...  A WAE flight wheel is shown in figure 5.

A flight wheel is one fitted for the flight, that is, the final version from development and testing.

Comment: Yes, I guess in contrast to those used for on-earth testing, which would likely have been stronger. I don't find this to be obvious terminology, partly because I don't think I think of the rover's mission as a "flight". "Mars wheel" or "mission wheel" would be more obvious. Perhaps in NASA's terminology, all phases of a mission are part of the "flight".

Comment: @CCTO Or "production wheel" as opposed to "prototype wheel".